# Access Smartcard data prior to giving a PIN

Tags: java, smartcard, pkcs#11

I'm developing a digital signature solution and would like to retrieve data (the name of the card holder or the subject of the certificate in the card) from a smartcard containing a digital certificate, BEFORE the user provides the card's pin. I'm aware of other solutions that do that, however I haven't been able to do the same.

I'm using the following Java APIs:

- Java PKCS#11 (with this API I have been able to get that information, after loading the contents of the card to a KeyStore, but only after the PIN has been provided) and
- smartcardio (with this API I have been able to test the presence or absence of the card in the terminal)

I wonder if anyone could have a hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What the card requires to allow access to certain data depends on a stage called *card personalization*, and is completely independent from the used API. You should urgently check, what the card personalization documents state. Hint: if you get "security status not satisfied", 0x6982, the card seems not to support your desired approach.

---

After reading your comment: it seems, that you are reading the local certificate storage and don't communicate with the card; you just rely on some magic process having read and stored the certificate earlier. This is an entirely different question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation, @guidot. As I mentioned, I have been in contact with applications that do that and have been able, just yesterday, to fecht the certificate from the smartcard via MSCAPI. Unfortunatelly the API does not give complete control to the developer. With it was possible to read all the certificates present in the operating system and this includes those from the smart card. However the api doesn’t fetch the certificate from the sm if the card is absent from the reader terminal when the application starts running, only if it is there from the start.

Comment: That's what happens in a certain way when I get the certificate via MSCAPI. Windows scans the system and puts all the certificates found in the repository. In the beginning of the application it is from there that comes the Information about the certificate present in the smartcard. In a later stage, when the user wishes to sign a document, it is necessary to grab the key from the card, and that's when the pin must be given.